# How can I prove $p \mid n^p - n$ for $n$ natural and $p$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, divisibility

Good evening!

It seems I am not able to prove the following statement:

> If $n$ is natural and $p$ is prime, then $p$ divides $n^p - n$.

I'd be grateful for any help with this problem!

Comment: This is [called Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). It says that it's true for all $n$ integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by induction:

If $n=1$ then it is obvious. Now do the induction step from $n$ to $n+1$.

By induction hypothesis we have $n^p-n=p\cdot d$.

It is easy to see that $p\mid {p\choose k}$ if $1\leq k \leq p-1$ since we have $$k{p\choose k} = p{p-1\choose k-1}$$
Now we use binomial theorem:

\begin{eqnarray*}
  (n+1)^p-(n+1) &=& n^p + \underbrace{{p\choose 1}n^{p-1}+...+{p\choose p-1}n}_a+1-n-1 \\
   &=& \underbrace{n^p-n}_{p\cdot d} + p\cdot b \\
 &=& p (d+b)
  \end{eqnarray*}
where $a = p\cdot b$

Comment: To prove that $p\mid \binom{p}{k}$ you can notice that $\binom{p}{k}=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$ and $p$ is a prime that divides the numerator but does not divide the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the proof here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem
Just you should know a bit elementary Number Theory!